How do I update text frame size in Dynamic Island swiftui
Im using a timer in my app and in the view inside of the dynamic island live activity im using the Text(timerInterval: )  initializer that I believe its the right thing to use when displaying countdown in live activities. The thing is that whenever the starting time is more than 10 min the size is right but whenever the digits change to 9:59 and the text gets smaller (as it should) the frame doesn't and it leaves a space on the right that is not visually pleasing.
More than 10 mins with red background to highlight the space:

Less than 10 mins with red background to highlight the space:

As you can see there is a big space on the right when the timer is small in width. It is more noticeable when
.background(ContainerRelativeShape().fill())  is used:
More than 10 min:

Less than 10 min:

Ive tried using .frame  with maxwidth and idealwidth, adjusting the .padding  or even trying to get the string from the timeInterval and adjusting the frame according to the text size and I also tried to get the first 2 digits before the ":" to display only minutes and not minutes and seconds but nothing at all, it didn't move.
Here is my current code:
      } compactLeading: {
        Label("JFK", systemImage: "airplane.departure")
          .padding(4)
          .background(ContainerRelativeShape().fill(.green.opacity(0.8)))
      } compactTrailing: {
        let timerInterval = Date()...Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(60 * context.state.time))
        
        Group {
          Text("in ") + Text(timerInterval: timerInterval, showsHours: false) + Text(" min")
        }
        .frame(idealWidth: 90, maxWidth: 100, alignment: .center)
        .padding(4)
        .background(ContainerRelativeShape().fill(.red))
        
      }


If you specify a maxWidth then I would expect, it is always used. Have you tried it without?

Nope even taking out the .frame line it stays the same

Try removing the .frame, removing the .padding, and changing it to .background { Color.red } (using curly braces, exactly as shown here). That should reduce the background red color to the minimum possible size. If that works then it lets you explore, what is causing the excess size. If it doesn't work, it means the size for the Text counter is allocated on initial display and then never changes. In the latter case, you will probably need to implement a custom counter instead.

Yep it seems that I will need to implement a custom counter, when there is no background it looks pretty bad, using the .background it looks the same as the other approach, thanks tho.
